# list users with quota over specified value in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, quota

I have been spending a lot of time trying to create a quota check script and have not gotten the results I need.

I am using a for loop to iterate an awk command to search for a value greater than 3000000.

Base of command to output quota:

```
for i in `awk '{print $2}' /etc/userdomains |  grep -v "nobody" | sort -u`
do
  quota -v -u $i
done
```

Output per iteration:

```
Disk quotas for user exampleuser (uid 2599): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
      /dev/sda1       8       0       0              10       0       0        
      /dev/sdb1       0       0       0               0       0       0        
      /dev/sdc1   57792       0       0            2511       0       0        
      /dev/sdd1       0       0       0               0       0       0        
      /dev/sde1       0       0       0               0       0       0
```

I intend to pipe an awk command to print line 1; field 5 AND line equal or greater than 3; field 2 if field 2 is greater than 50000

So the wanted output would be:

```
exampleuser
57792
```

OR

```
exampleuser 57792
```

So far I cannot get these results using different methods in awk.

Here are my last two tries (based off value greater than 3000000):

```
for i in `awk '{print $2}' /etc/userdomains |  grep -v "nobody" | sort -u`
do
    quota -v -u $i | awk '{ if ($2 >= 3000000) print $0 ; else;}'
done
```

Output:

```
Disk quotas for user bforrest (uid 2108): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
Disk quotas for user bible (uid 500): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
      /dev/sdc1 12230716       0       0           10168       0       0        
Disk quotas for user bigbeau (uid 1608): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
Disk quotas for user bilgem (uid 3299): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
Disk quotas for user billbell (uid 2872): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
Disk quotas for user biosalus (uid 3215): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
Disk quotas for user bkeating (uid 1104): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
      /dev/sdc1 3106480       0       0            9636       0       0        
Disk quotas for user blaaraba (uid 2931): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
Disk quotas for user blackbird (uid 1666): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
```

Another one:

```
for i in `awk '{print $2}' /etc/userdomains |  grep -v "nobody" | sort -u`
do
    quota -v -u $i \
      | awk '{ if (NR >= 3 && $2 >= 3000000) print $0 ; else;}' \
      | cut -d "*" -f1
done
```

Output:

```
  /dev/sdc1 55948456       0       0           45806       0       0        
  /dev/sdd1 91428904       0       0           97739       0       0        
  /dev/sdd1  512000
  /dev/sdc1 60275820       0       0           10594       0       0        
  /dev/sdb1  512460
  /dev/sdb1 93819732       0       0           47951       0       0        
  /dev/sdd1 527613532       0       0           11935       0       0        
  /dev/sdd1 56922524       0       0           60761       0       0        
  /dev/sdc1  307664
  /dev/sdb1 65851960       0       0          257999       0       0
```

Maybe my method is totally off. Any thoughts on this?

#### UPDATE:

Found a better command (`repquota -a`) to report quota. Much more consistent since it doesn't vary depending on where files are located:

```
for i in `awk '{print $2}' /etc/userdomains |  grep -v "nobody" | sort -u`
do
    repquota -a | awk {'print $1 " " $3'} | grep -w $i \
      | awk '{if ($2 >= 5000000) print $0 ; else;}'
done
```

Output:

```
a4fundjs 55948456
actifeve 12535196
aepromo 13224160
```

Comment: As the answer shows, you are doing far too much work for the task. If you are going to use awk, learn it.

Answer (score 0):

For you original input

```
awk 'NR==1{print $5} NR>2 && $2>50000 {print $2}'
```

will print

```
exampleuser                                                                                                                                                                                                 
57792
```

Comment: Will still print usernames even if not matched with line >2 field two that is greater than number: for i in `awk '{print $2}' /etc/userdomains |  grep -v "nobody" | sort -u`; do quota -v -u $i | awk 'NR==1{print $5} NR>2 && $2>30000000 {print $2}';done I am updating my post to reflect a better way to do this.

Comment: Yes, they are in different `condition{action}` blocks. If you want username to be conditionally printed you can do something like this (not tested!) `awk 'NR==1{u=$5} NR>2 && $2>50000 {print u, $2}'`